# How to vertically align li elements in ul?

Tags: css

I want to align vertically my `li` elements in the middle of `ul` depending on the screen width. I've found code which helps my to achieve my goal but when I change width of the screen I see that my polaroid photos are ruined.

Something affects my code and I am not able to find the reason.

```css
.pics {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.pics a {
  background: #fff;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 10px 30px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all .30s;
  -moz-transition: all .30s;
  -o-transition: all .30s;
  transition: all .30s;
  position: absolute;
}

.pics img {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.pics a:hover {
  z-index: 100;
}
.pics a:after {
  content: attr(title);
}

.pics li:nth-child(1n) a {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) scale(0.7, 0.7);
  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg) scale(0.7, 0.7);
  transform: rotate(30deg) scale(0.7, 0.7);
  top: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

.pics li:nth-child(2n) a {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg) scale(0.7, 0.7);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg) scale(0.7, 0.7);
  transform: rotate(-30deg) scale(0.7, 0.7);
  top: 0;
  left: 5%;
}

.pics li:nth-child(3n) a {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg) scale(0.7, 0.7);
  -moz-transform: rotate(40deg) scale(0.7, 0.7);
  transform: rotate(40deg) scale(0.7, 0.7);
  top: 30%;
  left: 65%;
}

.pics li:nth-child(4n) a {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg) scale(0.7, 0.7);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg) scale(0.7, 0.7);
  transform: rotate(-30deg) scale(0.7, 0.7);
  top: 20%;
  left: 25%;
}

.pics li:nth-child(n) a:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.9);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.9);
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.9);
}

@media handheld,
only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .pics li {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .pics li img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .pics li a {
    width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .pics li:nth-child(1n) a {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg) scale(0.5, 0.5);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg) scale(0.5, 0.5);
    transform: rotate(-30deg) scale(0.5, 0.5);
    top: -10%;
    left: 0;
  }
  .pics li:nth-child(2n) a {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.5, 0.5);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.5, 0.5);
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.5, 0.5);
    top: 10%;
    left: 0;
  }
  .pics li:nth-child(3n) a {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) scale(0.5, 0.5);
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg) scale(0.5, 0.5);
    transform: rotate(30deg) scale(0.5, 0.5);
    top: 0;
    left: -10% !important;
  }
  .pics li:nth-child(4n) a {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg) scale(0.5, 0.5);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg) scale(0.5, 0.5);
    transform: rotate(-30deg) scale(0.5, 0.5);
    top: 0;
    left: 10%;
  }
  .pics li:nth-child(n) a:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.6);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.6);
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.6);
  }
  ul.pics {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .pics a:after {
    font-size: 1.9em !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="pics">
  <li>
    <a href="http://localhost/index.php/galeria/sprzet/" title="Sprzet">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://localhost/index.php/galeria/sprzet/" title="Sprzet">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://localhost/index.php/galeria/sprzet/" title="Sprzet">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://localhost/index.php/galeria/sprzet/" title="Sprzet">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<!--pics -->
```

Comment: Looks alright to me, what browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox but I know that I'm doing something wrong. I didn't tell you that I want to keep defualt size of my image. To do that in .pics li and .pics li a I've used height: auto, but when I use option "auto" i can't have my li elements in the middle of ul. I center my li elements only when I tell amount height in px or in %

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS includes a media query which is manipulating your content when the viewport is resized.  Try adding the following to your CSS:

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   .pics li { 
       display: block; 
   }
   .pics li a { 
       float: none; 
       position: relative; 
   }
}
```

Comment: I add media because I want to make changes in such a view. And now I want to keep my photos in the middle of ul without destroying images.

Comment: I've updated the CSS with some changes that will stack the photos when viewed responsively.  I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Shall I remove any option in my code before adding or can i just copy your tips to mine

Comment: Try moving my code into the proper selectors and give it a whirl.

Comment: Thanks for help but it is not working however you gave me good tracks :]

Comment: Those styles might be getting overridden.  Try adding `!important` to each.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and if it works I will inform you about it